# I'm having an issue w/ Action Script 2.0 for The Matrix cascading code

Tags: flash, actionscript

I found this great tutorial for "Matrix" cascading code in Flash, but the code has errors. The full tutorial and code is at [Flash Matrix - Animated Code Effect](http://www.pixelhivedesign.com/tutorials/Flash+Matrix+-+Animated+Code+Effect/) ...

Here's the part of the code w/ the problem (lines 75 - 88):

**

```
if(this.ind < this.myCodes.length and this.delay != 0){
this.ind++;
this.delay--;
} else {
this.ind = 0;
this.delay = this.myCodes.length;
}
```

**

When I test it I get error:

**Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 75, Column 35     1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before and.**

When I placed the rightparen before and, I get error:

**Symbol 'one_pod', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 80, Column 3    1083:         Syntax error: else is unexpected.**

... and haven't found a fix for the else... I'm not a good actionscripter so kind of hit a wall here... Any ideas?

Thanks!

(I emailed the author re/ this but he hasn't responded...)

Comment: _"I'm not a good actionscripter"_ so start with AS3 language, not the almost-obsolete AS2.

Comment: Your absolutely right, but this tute has the best looking result... Otherwise, yes, I only work in AS3...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **AND** operator (`&&`) instead of the word `and` in your code:

```
if( (this.ind < this.myCodes.length) && (this.delay != 0) )
{
    this.ind++;
    this.delay--;
} 
else 
{
    this.ind = 0;
    this.delay = this.myCodes.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I did it and got this error: Symbol 'one_pod', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 75, Column 55 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.
But I appreciate the suggestion :)

Comment: Oops, I mean this error:                                                                                    Symbol 'one_pod', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 75, Column 36 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before logicaland.
Symbol 'one_pod', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 75, Column 57 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.

Comment: After looking at the tut code... (1) Where does `this.myCodes.length` and that `this.delay` suddenly come from? Previously it was always `codeLines.myCodes.length` and `codeLine.ind` and `codeLine.delay` etc... maybe use those?... (2) Use `trace` to check variables values, so before the `If` statement, just `trace( "this.ind is: " + this.ind);` and also `trace( "this.myCodes.length is: " + this.myCodes.length);` you get numbers (not a "null" or "undefined")? (3) If in doubt just [**show all code used**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46966081/edit) since problem could be from previous line...